# Create Directory on External SDCard in Cordova

Tags: cordova

I am trying to create a directory on my external SDCard. I am able to do so on the internal SD. The below code will return error code 12. What am I doing incorrectly?

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fs) {
            console.log("Root = " + fs.root.fullPath);
            fs.root.fullPath = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory;
            fs.root.getDirectory("newDir", {create: true, exclusive: false},
                function(dirEntry) {
                    dirEntry.getFile("newFile.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, function (fileEntry) {
                        console.log("File = " + fileEntry.fullPath);
                    }, function (error) {
                        alert(error.code);
                    });
                }, function (error) {
                   alert(error.code);
                });
           }, function (error) {
                   alert(error.code);
           });
```

Answer (score 6):

try to use : **window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL** this works fine

```
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, function(fileSystem) {
            console.log("Root = " + cordova.file.externalRootDirectory);
            fileSystem.getDirectory("newDir", {create: true, exclusive: false},

            function(dirEntry) {
                dirEntry.getFile("newFile.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, function (fileEntry) {
                    console.log("File = " + fileEntry.fullPath);
                }, function (error) {
                    alert(error.code);
                });
            }, function (error) {
               alert(error.code);
            });
       }, function (error) {
               alert(error.code);
       });
```